# Qt SSL Support Not Working

Tags: c++, qt, ssl

Now I know there are TONS of posts that regard issue like this, but I've been through a lot of them and none seem to fix my issue. I have the standard issue of not being able to do a GET or POST request on a SSL encrypted address. Eg: `https://google.com` As far as I can tell, I've done everything right. Here is what I've done:

- Set a ssl certificate:

  ```
  QFile file("://cacert.pem");
  file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
  const QByteArray bytes = file.readAll();
  const QSslCertificate certificate(bytes);
  QSslSocket::addDefaultCaCertificate(certificate);
  ```
- Set a ssl protocol:

  ```
  QSslConfiguration sslconfig;
  sslconfig.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1_0);
  ```
- Added ALL the OpenSsl dlls into my executable's directory

However, still no avail. My program shows ssl error, no call to the `QNetworkReply::encrypted()` signal, and `QSslSocket::supportsSsl()` still returns false.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am just now sure what to do at this point.

EDIT:

- Added a slot to be called upon QNetworkReply's `sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)` that will debug it:(Hasn't been called at this point.)

  ```
  connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList)), this, SLOT(debugSslErrors(QList &)));
  ```
- Also added a check for when my certificate is opened:(Opens successfully)

  ```
  if (!certFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
      {
          qDebug() << "Couldn't Open Resource File.";
          qDebug() << "Error: " << certFile.errorString();
          return;
      }
  ```

Here is my PRO File:

```
    #-------------------------------------------------
    #
    # Project created by QtCreator 2017-03-28T17:43:36
    #
    #-------------------------------------------------

    QT       += core gui network
    CONFIG   += c+=11
    greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

    TARGET = Gallery
    TEMPLATE = app

    # The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
    # any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
    # depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
    # deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
    DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

    # You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
    # In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
    # You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
    #DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


    SOURCES += main.cpp\
            mainwindow.cpp \
        base.cpp \
        post.cpp \
        responsepost.cpp \
        md5data.cpp \
        tagdata.cpp \
        postcreationdialog.cpp \
        postgetdialog.cpp \
        sslcipher.cpp

    HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
        base.h \
        post.h \
        sides.h \
        responsepost.h \
        md5data.h \
        tagdata.h \
        postcreationdialog.h \
        postgetdialog.h \
        sslcipher.h

    FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
        postcreationdialog.ui \
        postgetdialog.ui

    RESOURCES += \
        files.qrc

    LIBS += ../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/libcrypto32MT.lib
    LIBS += ../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/libcrypto32MTd.lib
    LIBS += ../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/libeay32.lib
    LIBS += ../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/libssl.lib
    LIBS += ../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/libssl32MD.lib
    LIBS += ../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/libssl32MDd.lib
    LIBS += ../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/libssl32MT.lib
    LIBS += ../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/libssl32MTd.lib
    LIBS += ../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/openssl.lib
    LIBS += ../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/ossltest.lib
    LIBS += ../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/padlock.lib
    LIBS += ../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/ssleay32.lib
    LIBS += ../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/capi.lib
    LIBS += ../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/dasync.lib
    LIBS += ../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/Gdi32.Lib
    LIBS += ../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/GdiPlus.lib
    LIBS += ../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/libcrypto.lib
    LIBS += ../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/libcrypto32MD.lib
    LIBS += ../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/libcrypto32MDd.lib


    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/include
    DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../Libraries/OpenSSL-Win32/include
```

Comment: What is the Ssl error you are getting? Have you checked the result of a call to QSslSocket:;sslErrors()? Have you checked that the the certificate is being found/loaded correctly?

Comment: @ManuelH I will add the `sslError()` slot. How can I check for certificate loading besides in the qfile open.

Comment: For simply loading the certificate into a QFile, checking the result of QFile::open() is enough. Just remember to look at QFile::error() to find out why it failed to open if QFile::open() returns false.

Comment: @ManuelH i mean I'm opening a resource file so I'd assume it's work fine, but I'll still implement that.

Comment: @ManuelH Just fixed the issues/reccomendations you suggested.

Comment: "QSslSocket::supportsSsl() still returns false.", well, your platform doesn't support SSL then. Do you have any SSL libraries (OpenSSL) installed? Check http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/opensslsupport.html

Comment: @ManuelH yes. I have OpenSSL installed in the C:/directory. Also I have and OpenSSL dlls in the application root. I also dynamically linked all the OpenSSL libs in the pro file.

Comment: Show your .pro file

Comment: @ManuelH Just added it in!

Comment: When you run your application in debug mode, have a look at the "Modules" window in QtCreator to see which libraries are being loaded and check for the OpenSSL ones.

Comment: Verify that libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll are being loaded.